# jQuery, Switch-Case to Show Multiple Selected Options With the Same Class

Tags: jquery, select, switch-statement

The following jQuery code works to show only the selected option if there  is only 1 element (`<tr>`) with that class, but all are hidden if there are multiple elements with the class.  What is needed to be changed?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#genre").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");
    switch (id) {
      case "opt_all":
        $("tr").show();
        break;
      case "opt_family":
        $(".family").show().siblings().hide();
        break;
      case "opt_life":
        $(".lifestyle").show().siblings().hide();
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='genre' id='genre'>
      <option id='opt_all' selected='selected'>All Genre</option>
      <option id='opt_family'>Family &amp; Friends</option>                
      <option id='opt_life'>Lifestyle</option>    
    </select>
<table>
  <tr class="family"></tr>
  <tr class="life"></tr>
  <tr class="family"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Because `siblings()` picks any sibling elements when called without a sibling, even ones in the original selector (which `siblings()` is unaware of). You would want to remove any like `.siblings(':not(.lifestyle)')` for instance. Or invert it and do the hide first, then show. That's probably easier.

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kd07q3bb/ vs this: https://jsfiddle.net/kd07q3bb/1/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!  Adding the ':not(.__)' works!  You made my day. @Jared Farrish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to reverse it: hide, then show.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#genre").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");
    switch (id) {
      case "opt_all":
        $(this).show();
        break;
      case "opt_family":
        $('.tr').hide().filter(".family").show();
        break;
      case "opt_life":
        $('.tr').hide().filter(".lifestyle").show();
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

Or negate it on filter selection of `siblings()` so you exclude what you've just operated on:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#genre").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");
    switch (id) {
      case "opt_all":
        $("tr").show();
        break;
      case "opt_family":
        $(".family").show().siblings(':not(.family)').hide();
        break;
      case "opt_life":
        $(".lifestyle").show().siblings(':not(.lifetyle)').hide();
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use .each for elements with same selector:

```
$(".family").each(function(index,element){
  element.hide();
})
```

Comment: That is completely unnecessary and doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you!  I will have to try this.  It looks like a more efficient way.